# Can I use Redis container [Docker] as cluster?

Tags: php, docker, redis, docker-compose, predis

I am using docker-compose to configure containers for my Dev Env and I have 3 containers ( nginx, php, redis )

```
version: '3'

services:
    php:
        ..
    nginx:
        ..
    redis:
        image: redis
        ports:
          - 6379:6379
```

I am using [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis) to connect to redis from php container , my question is : I am trying to work in clustering mode, when I do something like that

```
$parameters = ['redis'];
$options    = ['cluster' => 'redis'];

$client = new Predis\Client($parameters, $options);
```

is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by changing the host url like that

```
$parameters = ['redis://redis'];
```

you can find may schemes available on Predis if you go to [Predis Connection Factory](https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v1.1/src/Connection/Factory.php#L25)

and Predis support may protocols to communicate with an instance of Redis

*tcp (TCP/IP), unix (UNIX domain sockets) or http (HTTP protocol through Webdis)*

like it mention in [Connection Parameters](https://github.com/nrk/predis/wiki/Connection-Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to get the IP address of the redis container for the connection.

(Assumin Linux) Run `docker ps` to find the name of the container (may be docker_redis_1), then `docker inspect <container name> | grep IPAddress`.  Use this IP address in the connection -

```
$options    = ['cluster' => '<IP Address of container>'];
```

Comment: Would be more useful if you gave some more information than 'it's not working'.  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: well, I tried to do somthing like that 

$parameters = ['tcp://172.19.0.4:6379']

but client was not able to establish the connection